# column is of unsupported class data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use mutate to perform calculation, the calculation looks like this

```
a %>% mutate(volume = Period2_DOS)
```

However, this code gives me the error below:

> Error: Column `volume` is of unsupported class data.frame.

However, when I changed `Period2_DOS` to `period1_price` variable, it worked. So I think the problem might be `Period2_DOS` variable.

It looks like this:

[image]

How can I run the code above?

Comment: Can you show the `dput` of 'a' or `str(a)`.  Also, in the image there is no `_` in the column name 'Period2DOS`

Comment: Hello Akrun, it turned out that the problem lies in the underscore.... detail matters :) thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column names should be matched.  It would be

```
library(dplyr)
a %>% 
     mutate(volume = Period2DOS)
```